# Infinite recursion while using an attached property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties, dynamicresource

I have a need to set `Content` property of a `ContentPresenter` to a `DynamicResource`, which key is known at runtime. `DynamicResource`'s `Key` is not a dependency property, so I cannot insert a binding there, and that's why I've created an attached property, which serves as a proxy for the `Content`:

```
public static class ContentPresenterHelper {

    private static void ContentResourceKeyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {

        var element = d as ContentPresenter;
        if (element != null) {

            element.SetResourceReference(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, e.NewValue);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentResourceKeyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ContentResourceKey",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(ContentPresenterHelper),
        new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty, ContentResourceKeyChanged));

    public static void SetContentResourceKey(ContentPresenter element, object value) {

        element.SetValue(ContentResourceKeyProperty, value);
    }

    public static object GetContentResourceKey(ContentPresenter element) {

        return element.GetValue(ContentResourceKeyProperty);
    }
}
```

I'm using it in the following way:

```
<ContentPresenter u:ContentPresenterHelper.ContentResourceKey="{Binding SomeProp}" />
```

I've used similar approach when assigning dynamically image from resources to an `Image`'s `Source` property and that worked.

However, in this particular case attempt to solve the problem in the way I've shown results in an infinite recursion:

```
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.IsLoaded.get()    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.FrameworkObject.IsLoaded.get()    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.IsParentLoaded(System.Windows.DependencyObject d) Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.IsLoaded.get()    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.FrameworkObject.IsLoaded.get()    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.IsParentLoaded(System.Windows.DependencyObject d) Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.IsLoaded.get()    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.FrameworkObject.IsLoaded.get()    Unknown
...
```

Why is it so? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When messing around with `ContentPresenter`, always remember that `ContentPresenter.Content` is a very special property: it affects the `DataContext`. In combination with data binding this can produce all sorts of weird effects. Generally speaking, binding `ContentPresenter.Content` through `DataContext` is not reliable and should be avoided. Try using `ContentControl`, as it does not connect its `DataContext` to `Content` in this manner. Also, instead of an attached property, I'd write a converter to look up your dynamic resource by key, and use it to bind `Content` directly, but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: The only problem with converter is, that it does not have immediate access to resources. I'd have to manually attach a `ResourceDictionary` while instantiating the converter, wouldn't I? Or maybe there's some more clever trick to give converter access to resources?

Comment: That depends on how your resources are scoped. If the resources you are targeting are at application scope, you can get by without access to the local context. However, it is possible to create converters which have access to the local context, by deriving from `MarkupExtension`. It gets tricky with templates though. Anyway, converter vs attached property is a matter of taste.

Comment: Anyway; exchanging `ContentPresenter` with `ContentControl` solved my problem completely; thank you for help, sir :)